# Upon landing on the form again, the previous selection of the multiselect value option is repeating when fetched from the browser's localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 for multiselect options in Thymeleaf form. I have a requirement that after clicking submit, when you return to the same form, the previous selections should be retained. Only upon clicking the clear button should you be able to clear the selections. All other options are working as expected, except for the project name. When I select the project name and other values and click submit, it generates a graph. Upon clicking the back button, I see that all other option selections are the same as the previous selections, except for the project name, which is repeating. Below is the image for reference.

**Before Submit Of form**
[image]

**After Submit of form and Click Back button**

[image]

**You see the connect is repeating i am not sure why this is happening below is the form and js file**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Defect Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="defectdashboard.css">
    <link href="custom_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header with company logo -->
<div class="header-bar">
    <!-- Back to Form Button on the left -->
    <a   class="nav-link" href="/">
        <span class="button-home">
            <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:35px;" title="Home"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
    <!-- Defect Dashboard in the middle -->
    <h1 class="dashboard-defect">Defect Dashboard</h1>

    <img src="pngLogo.png" id="nike-image" alt="Nike Logo" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-right: 28px;display:none;">
    <!-- Company Logo on the right -->
</div>
<!-- Form Section -->
<section class="container mt-3" id="form-section">
    <div class="spinner" id="spinner" style="display: none;">
        <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <form action="submit" method="POST" th:object="${defectModel}">
        <!-- Project Name Dropdown -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="projectName">Project Name</label>
            <select id="projectName" name="projectName" class="form-control" th:field="*{projectName}" multiple>
                <option th:each="project : ${projectNames}" th:value="${project}" th:text="${project}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Squad Dropdown -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="squad">Squad</label>
            <select id="squad" name="squad" class="form-control" th:field="*{squad}" multiple>
                <option th:each="squad : ${squads}" th:value="${squad}" th:text="${squad}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="label">Labels</label>
            <select id="label" name="label" class="form-control" th:field="*{label}" multiple>
                <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                <option th:each="label : ${labels}" th:value="${label}" th:text="${label}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="monthlyOption">Monthly</label>
            <select id="monthlyOption" name="monthlyOption" class="form-control" th:field="*{monthlyOption}" multiple>
                <option th:each="monthlyOption : ${monthlyOptions}" th:value="${monthlyOption}"
                        th:text="${monthlyOption}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quarter">Quaterly</label>
            <select id="quarter" name="quarter" class="form-control" th:field="*{quarter}" multiple>
                <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                <option th:each="quaterlyData : ${quaterly}" th:value="${quaterlyData}"
                        th:text="${quaterlyData}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="yeartodate">Year To Date</label>
            <select id="yeartodate" name="yeartodate" class="form-control" th:field="*{yeartodate}" multiple>
                <option th:each="yto : ${yeartoDate}" th:value="${yto}" th:text="${yto}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="yearonyear">Year On Year</label>
            <select id="yearonyear" name="yearonyear" class="form-control" th:field="*{yearonyear}" multiple>
                <option th:each="yoy : ${yearOnYearList}" th:value="${yoy}" th:text="${yoy}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Multiselect Option -->
        <!-- Submit and Cancel Buttons -->
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" id="clearSelection" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<section class="container mt-3" id="chart-section" style="display:none">
    <div th:replace="fragments :: chart-content"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:50%">
        <a href="/defect?name=defectDashboard" class="btn btn-primary" id="backToFormBtn" style="display:none;margin-right:0.2rem">Back</a>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="errorModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="errorModalLabel">Error</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please Select Project Name Or Squad Or Label.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Js file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const multiselect = $('select[multiple]');
    multiselect.each(function () {
        const savedOptions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.id));
        if (savedOptions) {
            const currentOptions = $(this).val() || [];
            // Check if saved options include the first selected item
            const firstSelectedItem = currentOptions.length > 0 ? currentOptions[0] : null;
            const includeFirstItem = firstSelectedItem ? savedOptions.includes(firstSelectedItem) : false;
            // Merge options only if the first selected item is not in the saved options
            if (!includeFirstItem) {
                const mergedOptions = [...currentOptions, ...savedOptions];
                $(this).val(mergedOptions).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });
    $('#label').select2();
    $('#quarter').select2();
    $('#projectName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Projects...',
    });
    $('#label').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select Label...',
    });
     $('#quarter').select2({
                placeholder: 'Select Quareter...',
        });
    // Show/hide form and chart sections based on user interaction
    $("#form-section").show();
    $("#nike-image").show();
    $("#chart-section").hide();
    $("#backToFormBtn").hide();

    // Handle form submission
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        multiselect.each(function () {
            const selectedOptions = $(this).val();
            localStorage.setItem(this.id, JSON.stringify(selectedOptions));
        });
        var projectName = $("#projectName").val();
        var squad = $("#squad").val();
        var label = $("#label").val();
        if (projectName.length === 0 && squad.length === 0 && label.length === 0) {
            $("#errorModal").modal('show');
        } else {
            $("#errorModal").modal('hide');
            var montlyOption = $("#monthlyOption").val();
            var quarterlyOption = $("#quarter").val();
            var yearToYear = $("#yeartodate").val();
            var yearToDate = $("#yearonyear").val();
            if (montlyOption.length === 0 && quarterlyOption.length === 0 && yearToYear.length === 0 && yearToDate.length === 0) {
                $("#monthlyOption option").prop("selected", true);
                $("#quarter option").prop("selected", true);
                $("#yeartodate option").prop("selected", true);
                $("#yearonyear option").prop("selected", true);
            }
            $("#spinner").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr("method"),
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#spinner").hide();
                    // Hide the form and show the chart section
                    $("#form-section").hide();
                    $("#chart-section").show();
                    $("#backToFormBtn").show();
                    var chartData = JSON.parse(response);
                    google.charts.load('current', {
                        'packages': ['corechart']
                    });
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                        drawCharts(chartData);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Handle "Back to Form" button click
    $("#backToFormBtn").click(function () {
        $("#chart-section").hide();
        window.history.back();
    });

    function drawCharts(chartData) {
        drawBarChart('monthly-chart', chartData['Monthly'], 'Monthly Data');
        drawBarChart('quarterly-chart', chartData['Quarterly'], 'Quarterly Data');
        drawBarChart('year-on-year-chart', chartData['YearOnYear'], 'Year-on-Year Data');
        drawBarChart('year-to-date-chart', chartData['YearToDate'], 'Year-to-Date Data');
    }

    function drawBarChart(containerId, data, title) {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Label');
        dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        for (var key in data) {
            dataTable.addRow([key, parseInt(data[key])]);
        }

        var options = {
            title: title,
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            },
            chart: {
                title: title,
                subtitle: ''
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(containerId));
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
    $("#clearSelection").click(function () {
        multiselect.val(null).trigger('change');
        multiselect.each(function () {
            localStorage.removeItem(this.id);
        });
    });

    $('#label').on('select2:select select2:unselect', function (e) {
        if (e.params.data.id === 'ALL') {
            if (e.type === 'select2:select') {
                // If "ALL" is selected, select all other options except "ALL"
                $(this).find('option[value!="ALL"]').prop('selected', true);
                $(this).trigger('change');
            } else if (e.type === 'select2:unselect') {
                // If "ALL" is deselected, unselect all options
                $(this).val(null).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#quarter').on('select2:select select2:unselect', function (e) {
        if (e.params.data.id === 'ALL') {
            if (e.type === 'select2:select') {
                // If "ALL" is selected, select all other options except "ALL"
                $(this).find('option[value!="ALL"]').prop('selected', true);
                $(this).trigger('change');
            } else if (e.type === 'select2:unselect') {
                // If "ALL" is deselected, unselect all options
                $(this).val(null).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a answer for it in case if somebody having the same experience
problem was getting huge list  in options because of which select2 multiple option is acting weirdly in order to solve this i put list option value less then 150